# How to Make Search in List at SwiftUI with Using Model

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a newbie at SwiftUI and I'm trying to learn it. In my test project I want to make search in a `List` but in the tutorials that I saw, there wasn't any tutorial with using `struct` model in another file. I don't know how to handle it. I tried to write something but I wasn't successful. Could you help me to handle it? Thank you in advance for all your help. I put my codes below for inspection:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var filteredText: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(myFavorites) {favorite in
                        Section(header: Text(favorite.title)) {
                            ForEach(favorite.elements) { element in
                                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(chosenFavoriteElement: element)) {
                                    Text(element.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Favorite Book App").navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .searchable(text: $searchText).onChange(of: searchText) { search in
                      //I didn't wrote anyting down here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

FavoriteModel.swift

```
import Foundation

struct FavoriteModel : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var elements : [FavoriteElements]
}

struct FavoriteElements : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var imageName : String
    var description : String
}

let macOS = FavoriteElements(name: "MacOS", imageName: "macosventura", description: "MacOS 13 
Ventura")
let windows = FavoriteElements(name: "Windows", imageName: "windows11", description: "Windows 11")

let borusanMannesmann = FavoriteElements(name: "Borusan Mannesmann", imageName: "borusanlogo", description: "Borusan Mannesmann Boru A.Ş.")
let aselsan = FavoriteElements(name: "Aselsan", imageName: "aselsan", description: "Aselsan Askeri Sanayi")

let favoriteOperatingSystems = FavoriteModel(title: "Favorite Operating Systems", elements: [macOS, windows])
let favoriteCompanies = FavoriteModel(title: "Favorite Companies", elements: [borusanMannesmann, aselsan])

let myFavorites = [favoriteOperatingSystems, favoriteCompanies]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of what items the current list is showing using a `@State`:

```
@State private var favorites: [FavoriteModel] = myFavorites
```

If `myFavorites` is not a global constant, and instead something else in `self`, you can assign this in `onAppear` instead.

Use this `@State` in your `ForEach`es:

```
ForEach(favorites) { favorite in
    // ...
}
```

When the `searchText` changes, just update the state according to the search text.

```
.onChange(of: searchText) { search in
    updateFilteredFavorites(search)
}
```

You can do any kind of filtering you want to do in `updateFilteredFavorites`. For example:

```
func updateFilteredFavorites(_ searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
        favorites = myFavorites
        return
    }
    
    var temp = myFavorites
    for i in temp.indices {
        temp[i].elements = temp[i].elements.filter { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText) }
    }
    // Remove the empty sections
    favorites = temp.filter { !$0.elements.isEmpty }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need your help in this one too. I used the same stuff but I failed. Link of the question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807040/how-to-protect-filter-settings-when-searching-in-a-list-in-swiftui